# Using relative paths in Microsoft Outlook COM with win32com

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I created a function to send email of my output using `win32com.client` in a Ppython script.

```
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mail = app.CreateItem(0)
mail.Subject = 'Output file'
mail.Body = 'Output file'
mail.To = 'foo@bar.com'
attachment = 'E:\\python\\outputfile.xlsx'
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
mail.Send()
```

It works good but I have a small issue. It finds the attachment only if I give the entire path. For example,

```
attachment='outputfile.xlsx'
```

or

```
attachment="\\outputfile.xlsx"
```

causes the error

> 4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'File name or directory name is not valid.'

I want to make the code portable so that it could find the file from its own directory.

Comment: did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to `import os` and use [`os.path.abspath('outputfile.xlsx')`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath).